# How to Create a Range in an Excel Cell

Tags: excel

I have a multitude of ranges that I need to input in Excel cells to then reference in a `vlookup`.

For example, I have the number 46, and the ranges are 0-50, 51-100, etc. and each range has a value that corresponds to it in the proceeding column.  When I `vlookup`, it does not work for the way I out in these ranges.  So, how can I make it check it this 46 number is in the range 0-50, 51-100, etc. from this cell.

Essentially, how do I make Excel recognize that 0-50 in a cell is the range from 0 to 50 and that 46 corresponds to that range?

Comment: Are all ranges in steps of 50 or are there other ranges as well?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do this is to just split up the range into multiple cells..

```
A1 = 0
B1 = 50
C1 = 100

Then you can just take 46, and use something like: 
if 46 > A1 & < B1, then do this
else, do that
```

Or have you looked into conditional formatting? what is your end goal with this?

Answer (score 0):

What you're trying to do is not how `vlookup` works.
Instead of giving the input range as `0-50` in one cell, use the following:

```
A1 = 0
A2 = 50
A3 = 100
A4 = 175
A5 = 300

B2 = VLOOKUP(B1;A1:A6;1)
```

The range automatically starts where the previous range ends. Note that the numbers in A1 to A5 need to be sorted by size, otherwise `vlookup` does not work.

In my example, B1 is the cell which contains your value.

If all your ranges are in steps of 50, then you might get away with a much easier formula:

```
B2 = FLOOR(B1/50;1)
```